# k-fold cross validation using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have created an artificial neural network. I am trying to calculate the accuracy of the model using k-fold cross validation technique but after compiling the last line its not progressing any further, its stuck there for more than 20 mins. I am not able to figure out where I am going wrong. Can anyone please help me with this thing? Below is the code I have used.

Thanks in advance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Churn_Modelling.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 3:13].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 13].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])
labelencoder_X_2 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 2] = labelencoder_X_2.fit_transform(X[:, 2])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
X=X[:,1:]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from keras.models import Sequential #required to initialize ann
from keras.layers import Dense #required to build the layers of ann

def build_classifier():
    classifier=Sequential()
    classifier.add(Dense(kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="relu", input_dim=11, units=6))
    classifier.add(Dense(kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="relu", units=6))
    classifier.add(Dense(kernel_initializer="uniform", activation="sigmoid",units=1))
    classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return classifier
classifier=KerasClassifier(build_fn=build_classifier, batch_size=10, nb_epoch=100)
accuracies=cross_val_score(estimator=classifier,X=X_train,y=y_train,cv=10,n_jobs=-1)
```

Comment: Have you tried it with small dataset? I mean, maybe your dataset is large and it is supposed to run more than 20 mins.

Comment: no I haven't but in 20 mins shouldn't it give status for even a single epoch

Comment: It depends on input size but I just noticed that your code does not output anything. You probably would want to print `accuracies` variable. Are you sure that the code does not finish running or you think it does not finish because there is no output on the screen. Please add `print(accuracies)` line at the end to see if it is gonna output anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the exact same code. It seems Windows has an issue with "n_jobs", if you remove it by "accuracies = .." , it will start working. It's just that it could take long but it will work and show each epoch being updated.